# Has anyone implemented custom mentions in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, mentions

I need to implement a custom mentions in LWC component where external non-salesforce users can be mentioned, the mention text should be displayed as @{UserFirstName}{UserLastName} but the actual text sent to external server should have bare text user.externalGUID instead of the mention. Still in LWC this should be displayed as @{UserFirstName}{UserLastName}

I have performed some investigation and have found that mentioned are usually implemented through either a custom textarea processing or contenteditable div element.

Salesforce uses in the Ligtning Experience quill library to implement mentions.

I have found that there is [react plugin](https://github.com/afry/quill-mention/blob/master/src/quill.mention.js)  for this, but I can't use it inside LWC.

Quill library has a powerful rich text editor capabilities which I don't need, the only thing I need is mentions.

I have been debugging Salesforce mentions implementation to get idea how custom mentions can be implemented, but I feel I got totally lost, the only thing I understood it that Salesforce uses Quill library for that.

Should I use textarea or content editable div for this?

Should I try to find some JS library which implements this and is LWC-complaint or try to build this from scratch?

---

What I have tried so far:

I tried to use content editable div and clear up the innerHTML property

```
event.target.innerHTML = '';
```

and the populate the list of child elements

```
<div class="ql-editor slds-rich-text-area__content slds-text-color_weak slds-grow" data-gramm="false" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Share an update..." aria-expanded="true" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" onkeydown={keydown} onkeypress={keypress} onkeyup={keyup}>
<template for:each={children} for:item="child">
 <template if:true={child.isSpan}>
 <span key={child.index} contenteditable="false" class="ql-chatter-mention quill_widget_element" tabindex="-1" data-widget="chatterMention">{child.text}</span>
  </template>
 <template if:true={child.isText}>
  {child.text}
   </template>
 </template>
 </div>
```

However, when I tried to do this the second time, the previous three items no longer render despite there are five elements in the array list.

```
   this.children.push( {index:0,isText:true,text:event.target.innerText.substr(0, this.startPos - 1)});
   this.children.push( {index:1,isSpan:true,text:'@[' + user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name + ']'});
   this.children.push( {index:2,isText:true,text:event.target.innerText.substr(pos)});
```

I have even tried to reassign the array property

```
this.children = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.children));
```

but this didn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update for 20 Feb 2023:

I have decided to publish this component (input box with mentions) to AppExchange.

Meanwhile I can put here the link to the package version which contains the component

The link to install to productions and Dev Editions: is following:
https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t09000000BOYuAAO.

The link to install in sandboxes is following: https://test.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t09000000BOYuAAO

The link to documentation: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1H1D34UncLlbhjM6_dZWso0KZbyy7lcCqqeVCCyIMNwI/edit?usp=sharing

Detailed usage documentation https://docs.google.com/document/d/16UfAMUVsIU0iHoMVC4emNQiY3ASa3umWDKlmu-ikODI/edit?usp=sharing

---

After two weeks of investigation and exploring all the possible options, I decided to use [Quill library](https://quilljs.com/docs/quickstart/) (which Salesforce also uses for its internal mention implementation) and upload it into the `Static Resource` and then use it inside the `LWC` component to handle the content editing problem.

Some important parts of this solution.

**The first step.** Importing quill library into LWC

```
import QuillStaticResource from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/Quill";
```

**The second step.** In the `connectedCallback` I call imperative Apex to get the data from the data source. I maintain two properties: `users` and `filtered`, the first property contains all the record returned from Apex, and the second property contains only the user which match the search criteria and is updated client-side without a round-trip to the server.

**The third step.** I use some div with property `lwc:dom="manual"` and with class `mention-container` to use as a container for a Quill library to create content-editable div inside

```
<template>
    <div class="main MEDIUM" >
        <div class="publisherInputContainer" >
            <div class="input-section cuf-publisherInput forceChatterPublisherInput" data-aura-class="forceChatterPublisherInput">
                <div class="forceChatterMessageBodyInput" data-aura-class="forceChatterMessageBodyInput">
                    <div lwc:dom="manual" class="messageBodyWrapper mention-container slds-rich-text-editor slds-grid slds-grid_vertical slds-nowrap slds-has-focus forceChatterMessageBodyInputRichTextEditor">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**The fourth step.** On the first execution of the renderedCallback, I load the Quill script from the `Static Resource`, then on success load I query the mention container element and pass this into `initQuill` method.

```
renderedCallback() {
    if (!this.firstRender) {
        this.firstRender = true;
        Promise.all([
            //loadScript(this, QuillMention + '/src/quill.mention.js'),
            loadScript(this, QuillStaticResource + "/quill.js"),
            loadStyle(this, QuillStaticResource + "/quill.snow.css"),
        ])
            .then(() => {
                this.initQuill(
                    this.template.querySelector("div.mention-container"),
                    this
                );
            })
    }
}
```

**The fifth step.**

Copied the [Quill-mention library](https://github.com/afry/quill-mention/blob/master/src/quill.mention.js) to LWC and fixed any Lightning-Experience issues arised. `InitQuill` method is a result of concatenation of [Constants module code](https://github.com/afry/quill-mention/blob/master/src/constants/index.js), [Mention Blot module code](https://github.com/afry/quill-mention/blob/master/src/blots/mention.js) and [Mention class constructor](https://github.com/afry/quill-mention/blob/master/src/quill.mention.js)

To fix some LWC-Quill incompatibility, I made the following changes in the Quill library, in quill.js 2998 line

```
{
    key: 'hasFocus',
    value: function hasFocus() {
-      return document.activeElement === this.root;
+      return this.root._template && this.root._template.activeElement === this.root;
    }
  }, {
```

(this change is also mentioned in the eighth step)

and quill.core.js line 1987

```
-(_console = console)[method].apply(_console, args); // eslint-disable-line no-console
+if (console && console[method]) {
+    (_console = console)[method].apply(_console, args); // eslint-disable-line no-console
+}
```

**The sixth step.**

Copied [Utils module code](https://github.com/afry/quill-mention/blob/master/src/utils/index.js) and other methods from  [Mention class](https://github.com/afry/quill-mention/blob/master/src/quill.mention.js) into LWC.

**The seventh step.**

Updated `renderList` method to use Lightning classes. Updated `initQuill` method to create a set of embedded containers, similar to native Lightning Experience implementation. Also in `initQuill` method `options` object set the body of `renderItem` method to generate the desired output for my data

```
renderItem(item) {
    return `${item.first_name} ${item.last_name}`;
},
```

**The eighth step.**

Fixed two Lightning Experience issues with Quill.

For the first issue, when `Quill.getBounds` function fails with error `Uncaught TypeError: leaf.domNode.getBoundingClientRect is not a function` when try to use the library inside the LWC in Salesforce, I have submitted an issue to [the Quill JS repository](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/3330) and [provided a possible solution for that](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/pull/3331/files), however, the library owners didn't merge this PR into their develop branch as of 13th Apr 2021.

Another issue is with `hasFocus`. I think it is good idea to keep these two fixes as library overrides.

A fix for a `hasFocus` function

```
quill.selection.hasFocus = function () {
        return (
            this.root._template &&
            this.root._template.activeElement === this.root
        );
    };
```

Also, for this fix I set the `_template` property with a link to LWC template after `quill` is initialised.

```
quill.root._template = this.template;
```

A fix for a `getBounds` function

```
    quill.selection.getBounds = function (index) {
        var length =
            arguments.length > 1 && arguments[1] !== undefined
                ? arguments[1]
                : 0;

        var scrollLength = this.scroll.length();
        index = Math.min(index, scrollLength - 1);
        length = Math.min(index + length, scrollLength - 1) - index;
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-void
        let node = void 0,
            _scroll$leaf = this.scroll.leaf(index),
            _scroll$leaf2 = _slicedToArray(_scroll$leaf, 2),
            leaf = _scroll$leaf2[0],
            offset = _scroll$leaf2[1];
        if (leaf == null) {
            return null;
        }

        let _leaf$position = leaf.position(offset, true);

        let _leaf$position2 = _slicedToArray(_leaf$position, 2);

        node = _leaf$position2[0];
        offset = _leaf$position2[1];

        let range = document.createRange();
        if (length > 0) {
            range.setStart(node, offset);

            let _scroll$leaf3 = this.scroll.leaf(index + length);

            let _scroll$leaf4 = _slicedToArray(_scroll$leaf3, 2);

            leaf = _scroll$leaf4[0];
            offset = _scroll$leaf4[1];

            if (leaf == null) return null;

            let _leaf$position3 = leaf.position(offset, true);

            let _leaf$position4 = _slicedToArray(_leaf$position3, 2);

            node = _leaf$position4[0];
            offset = _leaf$position4[1];

            range.setEnd(node, offset);
            return range.getBoundingClientRect();
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-else-return
        } else {
            let side = "left";
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-void
            let rect = void 0;
            if (node instanceof Text || node.tagName === "#text") {
                if (offset < node.data.length) {
                    range.setStart(node, offset);
                    range.setEnd(node, offset + 1);
                } else {
                    range.setStart(node, offset - 1);
                    range.setEnd(node, offset);
                    side = "right";
                }
                rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
            } else {
                rect = leaf.domNode.getBoundingClientRect();
                if (offset > 0) side = "right";
            }
            return {
                bottom: rect.top + rect.height,
                height: rect.height,
                left: rect[side],
                right: rect[side],
                top: rect.top,
                width: 0,
            };
        }
    };
```

**The ninth step.**

I had to add declarations

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
/* eslint-disable @lwc/lwc/no-inner-html */
```

to the top of LWC Javascript file to avoid `eslint` warning and

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @lwc/lwc/no-async-operation
```

to the places where `setTimeout()` is used.

**The tenth step.**

Also I had to change the implementation of `highlightItem` method since it didn't work in Lightning experience, so I just changed the ending of that method into

```
if (scrollItemInView) {
        this.mentionList.childNodes[this.itemIndex].scrollIntoView();
    }
```

**The eleventh step.**

Finally I have added some `text` property

```
@api get text() {
    return this.quill.editor.delta.ops
        .map((x) =>
            "string" == typeof x.insert ? x.insert : x.insert.mention.id
        )
        .join("");
}

set text(value) {
    this.quill.setText(value);
}
```

**The twelfth step.**

On the last step I have replaced the previously used `lightning-textarea` tag on the parent component

```
<lightning-textarea class="slds-m-left_x-small" name="input1" label="Add a comment"></lightning-textarea>
```

into a label and my custom mention component

```
            <label class="slds-form-element__label">Add a comment</label>
            <c-mention></c-mention>
```

To retrieve the value from the component, I used `this.template.querySelector('c-mention').text` and to clear the value in the component I used `this.template.querySelector('c-mention').text = '';`

Comment: what api version your lwc is running ? I feel like there is some Locker issues now. I switched to an aura component with apiv39 and made it work but when I change the api version to a recent one, the component is throwing several errors. Thanks !

Comment: hmm, maybe there is some unrelated issue with Lightning Web Security feature? I have this in my production code and I haven't experiences any issues. Version of component is 53. <apiVersion>53.0</apiVersion>

Comment: hey @Patlatus - thanks so much for the detailed writeup. I am trying to do something similar for email composer. I see a 404 error when resolving the promise on below lines.

            loadScript(this, quilljs + '/quill.js'),
            loadStyle(this, quilljs + '/themes.snow.css')

the error I see is :
GET https://****-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/resource/1661462360000/quill/themes.snow.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
and 
GET https://****-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/resource/1661462360000/quill/quill.js 404 (Not Found)

I have installed quill-1.3.6.zip as static resource.

Comment: Rahul, did you load Static Resource?

Comment: yes I did. When I use a zip file I see 404. When I upload direct js file the promise always is rejected and the error is undefined 
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, quilljs)
        ])
            .then(() => {
                this.initQuill();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                debugger;
            }

Comment: do you have to play around the locker / security in your org ?

Comment: Have you tried to call it in renderedCallback?

Comment: yes. I will post the code as an answer.

Comment: loadScript(this, QuillStaticResource + "/quill.js") I used quill.js but I made some modification to that file which I mentioned in my answer

Comment: hi @Patlatus - would you mind sharing the quill.js code? which version of quillJs did you download ? I get 'Cannot use import statement outside a module' on the loadScript promise resolve. I tried replacing import with require statements but no luck.

Comment: I am thinking of packaging this component and posting it on AppExchange. However, I didn't have time to do this yet

Comment: thanks - did you use the quillJs from one of the releases here https://github.com/quilljs/quill/releases ? Does it not have 'import' statements ?

Comment: Hi @RahulBoinepally, I have built a package version containing this component.

The link to install to productions and Dev Editions: is following: 
https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t09000000BOYuAAO. 

The link to install in sandboxes is following: https://test.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t09000000BOYuAAO

The link to documentation: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1H1D34UncLlbhjM6_dZWso0KZbyy7lcCqqeVCCyIMNwI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Patlatus This post has been a great help and the managed package also works the best. But I have an additional requirement of adding the #tags along with the @ mentions. So I need to implement this from scratch. Do you have the complete source code somewhere on GitHub, would you mind sharing it?

Comment: @RahulGawale well, I haven't intended to open source that. Anyway, since now publishing to AppExchange requires security review fee and I can't publish it to AppExchange right now, I may publish it https://github.com/Patlatus/Quill-Mention

Comment: @Patlatus Sorry to hear about the review fee, I also abandoned one of my side projects for the same reason. Anyways, Thank you very much for generously open-sourcing the code. really appreciate it.